# Can't mount samba share, but can access using smbclient

Tags: ubuntu, windows, samba, mount

I have a network share on Windows server in my local network.
I can access this share using smbclient on my Ubuntu 13.10 (with installed cifs-utils package) desktop like this:

```
smbclient \\\\192.168.5.2\\source -W DOMAIN -U My.User.Name%my.password
```

but if try to mount this share using mount like this:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.5.2/source /mnt/192.168.5.2/ -o username=My.User.Name,domain=DOMAIN,password=my.password
```

I got error:

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I also tried to add corresponding line in /etc/fstab file, but it return same error on 'sudo mount -a'
I think it may have something to do with server setup - I disable ntlmv2 in smb.conf adding line:

```
client ntlmv2 auth = no
```

without that line smbclient method doesn't work either. But I still can't figure it for mount

Comment: Is there possibly another session to the server already established with different credentials? Only very recent versions permit multiple security tokens across the same channel.

Comment: No, there is no another session to this server

Comment: @ShockwaveNN have you ever figured out what the problem was?

Answer (score 2):

Could you check the `Security tab` of the Windows Share. Does `My.User.Name` exists in the `Group or user names box`? Could you check whether the user has enough rights? Could you open windows explorer, navigate to \\192.168.5.2 and check whether the directory appears?

If this works as you already have indicated in the question. Could you indicate whether you have installed `sudo apt-get install cifs-utils`?

I mount windows folders like this:

- `//<ip>/files /tmp/hello cifs credentials=/home/<user>/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0` at /etc/fstab
- credentials file:

  - username=user
  - password=pass
- `sudo mount -a` should mount the folder

Comment: Windows Server settings are correct - I use same credentials in 'smbclient' command and it works fine. Cifs-utils are installed and your method with .smbredentials file return same error - mount error(13): Permission denied

Comment: Which Windows version are you using?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, and also via the fstab-option, i get a Permission denied error

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you're using Group Policy to control settings on your Windows machine, however I had this exact same problem and fixed it in our environment.
I had set 'Server SPN target name validation' to 'Accept if provided by client'. This was enough to consistently give an error code of 13 NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED. Turning this setting off, and refreshing the policy on the Windows machine allowed mount.cifs to work.

If you're not using group policy, check the local security policy in case this setting is more restrictive.

Answer (score -1):

temporal workaround:
access it via GUI/nautilus and right click into the opened folder → open in terminal
it will open you a terminal inside of the virtual storage layer that can be used the same way as the mapped folder, the address is something like:
/run/user/100/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.5.2,share=source/